# apt clean apt autoremove

Tags: puppet, apt

So i would like to remove unwanted files ( /var/cache and old kernels in /boot) to free up some space using puppet script and add this script to puppet master to automatically run once every month. I am new to puppet and would like your help with the below script to be corrected if wrong.

exec { 'apt-autoremove':
command => '/usr/bin/apt autoremove',
age => ‘1m’,
recurse => 1,

}

exec { 'apt-clean':
command => '/usr/bin/apt clean',
age => ‘1m’,
recurse => 1,

}

Thanks

Comment: and what is the business related question or error? Does the script run? what error is shown? please update the question as currently i dont see neither the first nor the second in the statement :-)

Comment: I haven't ran the script yet. Would need your help in finishing the script.

Comment: we do not write this for you.